# Confusion about java dates comparison

Tags: java, compareto

### Pre-notes:

1. Yes, this is homework.
2. Our school's tutor is out for the day
3. My book is useless
4. I'm not exactly sure what to search for on google for help with my confusion...

### Question:

Anyway - The question / confusion that I have involves the first bit of code that I have in my program to test the `compareTo` method.

1. Would I use the variables at the top of the code as my variables in the `static void main` area, or assign new variables, like I do have?
2. The values in `public Date()`... <-- Is that the date that my code in `static void main` is comparing to?  (If so, I have a piece of code that I want to use that uses the current date, rather than what's in `Date()`).

I may have more questions later on, but I hope that someone can clear up my confusion better than my book or google has proven thus far.

### Code:

```
package date;
import java.util.*;

public class Date implements Comparable
{
     static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

     private int dMonth;  //Part a of confusion 1
     private int dDay;
     private int dYear;

    public Date()
    {
        dMonth = 1;  //Confusion 2
        dDay = 1;
        dYear = 1900;
    }
    public Date(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        dMonth = month;
        dDay = day;
        dYear = year;
    }
    public void setDate(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        dMonth = month;
        dDay = day;
        dYear = year;
    }
    public int getMonth()
    {
        return dMonth;
    }
    public int getDay()
    {
        return dDay;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return dYear;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return (dMonth + "." + dDay + "." + dYear);
    }
    public boolean equals(Object otherDate)
    {
        Date temp = (Date) otherDate;

        return (dYear == temp.dYear
                && dMonth == temp.dMonth
                && dDay == temp.dDay);
    }
    public int compareTo(Object otherDate)
    {
        Date temp = (Date) otherDate;

        int yrDiff = dYear - temp.dYear;
        if (yrDiff !=0)
            return yrDiff;

        int monthDiff = dMonth - temp.dMonth;
        if (monthDiff !=0)
            return monthDiff;

        return dDay - temp.dDay;           
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  //Part b of confusion 1
    {
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

        Date temp;

        System.out.print("Enter date in the form of month day year");
        month = console.nextInt();
        day = console.nextInt();
        year = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: your main code doesn't really use the class you built. Do you want to know how to use the class you built and compare a date you get via user input to a pre-defined date set in the system?

Comment: You should `implements Comparable<Date>` rather than the rawtype. Also avoid naming your classes identically to common JDK classes - this just causes confusion. Further you have an `equals` method but no `hashCode` method - this is considered very bad practice. Also your `equals` method is wrong.

Comment: You need to do some serious reading about object programming. You are supposed (I assume) to create a `Date` object and use it, so step1, take user input (with a `Scanner`), step2, create a `Date` object (*with* user input), step3 use this object. My advice, move your Date class elsewhere (one class for `Date`, one class for `main`) this will help you figure things out

Comment: DevZer0 and RC - The Date class is written exactly how the instructor wanted us to write it, and somehow - I think if it was written differently, I probably would understand it a tiny bit better.  Boris the Spider - we haven't even covered what hashCode is, hell we haven't covered half the stuff I've read or seen online trying to wrap my head around this stuff.

Comment: @BoppreH Thank you for clearing up the confusion points.  Perhaps they shouldn't have boggled my mind as much as they did, but Java, in general, confuses me.

Comment: This book will help immensely with your class: [Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/) from O’Reilly. The [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle may help too, but it's not as much fun.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, I think you need to read about the difference between static methods/attributes and the ones in instances. I think this is what you should be doing in the `main` method:

```
System.out.print("Enter date in the form of month day year");
Date date1 = new Date(console.nextInt(), console.nextInt(), console.nextInt());

System.out.print("Enter second date in the form of month day year");
Date date2 = new Date(console.nextInt(), console.nextInt(), console.nextInt());

System.out.println("Comparison result:");
System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));
```

Regarding your confusion points:

### Class attributes

```
 private int dMonth;  //Part a of confusion 1
 private int dDay;
 private int dYear;
```

These are special variables. Each instance (that is, every object created with `new Date`) has its own value for `dMonth`, `dDay` and `dYear`. It is not accessible from the `main` because `main` is a static method, and thus doesn't have access to instance variables.

If you didn't understand, at least you know the names to search further.

### Default constructor

```
public Date()
{
    dMonth = 1;  //Confusion 2
    dDay = 1;
    dYear = 1900;
}
```

Those values are used when you create a new `Date` object without specifying which month/day/year you want. So `new Date(2, 3, 2013)` means 2/3/2013, while `new Date()` means 1/1/1900.

Answer (score 2):

1. No you can't, `dMonth`, `dDay` and `dYear` are [member variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). If you want to use them directly inside your `main` method you will have to use the keyword `static` so that they become [class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). But no, that is not what you want.
2. Your main method is doing nothing useful really. Your confusion point 2 is a constructor:

   ```
   Date d = new Date(); // Data Instance -> First constructor
   d.getMonth(); // 1
   d.getDay(); // 1
   d.getYear(); // 1900

   Date d2 = new Date(2, 2, 1901); 
   d2.getMonth(); // 2
   d2.getDay(); // 2
   d2.getYear(); // 1901

   d2.setDate(3, 3, 1902);
   d2.getMonth(); // 3
   d2.getDay(); // 3
   d2.getYear(); // 1902 

   d.getMonth(); // Still 1 since member variables of d are independent of d2

   d.compareTo(d2); // -2 -> (1900 - 1902)
   ```

   You can create date instances inside your main method and use code like the one above to access member variables (probably the whole point of your exercise).